# Is there a difference with 胃 and おなか?

Tags: words, kanji

I checked around and it says here about the usage of 胃, however, I didn't see おなか there.

What is the difference in おなか and 胃, in pronunciation and usage?

Answer (score 4):

Both means *stomach*, but おなか or 腹【はら】 refers to the whole *abdomen*, while 胃【い】 specifically refers to [this organ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stomach) between the esophagus and the duodenum.